# How to save an exported report in client not server using Stimulsoft Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-excel, stimulsoft

I have a Stimulsoft report in my ASP.Net web application.

I want to export it using this C# code.

```
report.ExportDocument(StiExportFormat.Excel2007, "d:\\ExportedFile.xlsx", exportSettings);
```

but this code exports the report to server, not the client.

How can I save the report to client's storage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer by myself.

I should write the exported data to a MemoryStream, not a file. then send the MemoryStream to the Response of Current HttpContext.
In this way a download dialog will be open and ask about donwload path on Client storage.

```
MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
renderedReport.ExportDocument(StiExportFormat.Excel2007, memoryStream, exportSettings);

HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Emad.xlsx");
HttpContext.Current.Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(memoryStream.ToArray());
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use ExportDocument() method on the report

```
MemoryStream st = new MemoryStream();
report.ExportDocument(StiExportFormat.Excel2007, st);
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use StiReportResponse class.
It returns the report exported to specified format.

```
StiReportResponse.ResponseAsPdf(this, report);
StiReportResponse.ResponseAsExcel2007(this, report);
```

You cold get more information in the [Stimulsoft Programming Manual](http://www.stimulsoft.com/en/documentation/online/programming-manual/using_web_viewer_stireportrespose_class.htm).